# Indexed view referencing objects on two different schemas

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, clustered-index, materialized-view

When I try to create/alter a view to create an index like this

```
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX IDX_vSalPopulation
   ON sfdc.vSalPopulation (ID);
```

I get the following error message

> Msg 1938, Level 16, State 1, Line 40 Index cannot be created on view
> 'vSalPopulation' because the underlying object 'YR_TRM_SBTRM_TABLE'
> has a different owner.

When I check the tables I see that the tables are owned by different schemas

```
exec sp_tables 'dbo.YR_TRM_SBTRM_TABLE'
exec sp_tables 'vSalPopulation'
```

> ```
> TABLE_QUALIFIER     TABLE_OWNER       TABLE_NAME              TABLE_TYPE    REMARKS
> MyDB                dbo               YR_TRM_SBTRM_TABLE      TABLE         NULL 
> MyDB                sfdc              vSalPopulation          VIEW          NULL
> ```

The [documentation on indexed views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/views/create-indexed-views?view=sql-server-ver15) states that you cannot have an indexed view that references two different databases.

- The view must be created by using the `WITH SCHEMABINDING` option.
- The view must reference only base tables that are in the same database as
  the view.
- The view cannot reference other views. … etc

However, I have the **same database but two different schemas**. Maybe the problem is actually the third requirement? While I am not referencing other views, there are functions.  Maybe I misunderstand the error message. Permissions? So, generally, is it possible to have an indexed view that references objects from two different schemas?

A simplified definition of the view that gives me the same error looks like this

```
ALTER VIEW sfdc.vSalPopulation
   WITH SCHEMABINDING 
AS
SELECT DISTINCT
    ID
FROM dbo.CAN
INNER JOIN dbo.YR_TRM_SBTRM_TABLE YTS ON CAN.YR_CDE = YTS.YR_CDE
WHERE YTS.SBTRM_END_DTE > GETDATE()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think I found the answer [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3149466/index-cannot-be-created-on-view-reportingvirtualdataareaview1-error-du). Basically, grant authorization on my second schema to dbo:

```
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON SCHEMA::sfdc TO dbo
```

So, it really has to do with ownership/authorization rather than the schema itself.
See: https://www.sqlteam.com/articles/understanding-the-difference-between-owners-and-schemas-in-sql-server